# Writing DAO class to fill one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, dao, dto

I would like to know How could I create DAO classes to map One-To-Many relation ship.

I have a Car `table` and `Person` table with relation a person can have 1 or many cars.

I Started with DTO :

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public string Color{ get; set; }   
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Car> Cars;
}
```

Let's say I did a query :

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON P INNER JOIN CAR C ON P.ID = C.PERSON_ID ORDER BY P.ID
```

And have this data

[image]

So How could I create my DAO class to retreive from DB the persons data with corresponding cars they have ?

Thank you

Comment: Are you using any ORM for this ? Otherwise you have to go SQL way to populate your List<Car> Cars property.

Comment: @RishabhKumar No I don't use ORM. In fact I am stuck on how to pouplate my List<Car> !! 

Shoul I take line by line and as long as the Person id did'nt change i push a new instance to the list<Car> ?

Comment: What is your actual code to extract this data from your database? And what kind of database are you using?

Comment: I'll suggest you go with any ORM like Entity Framework, that will really ease you work. Else you have to go old style and fetch records from database via SQLCommand. Have you implemented the logic to extract the data yet ?

Comment: @RishabhKumar No not yet. I am working in it right now, call a procedure on oracle that give me the result